# Unable to display image to NSImageView from image URL

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, cocoa

I am trying to get an image to show up inside of a NSImageView. Here is my code:

```
- (IBAction)openExistingDocument:(id)sender {
NSOpenPanel* panel = [NSOpenPanel openPanel];

[panel beginWithCompletionHandler:^(NSInteger result){
    if (result == NSModalResponseOK) {
        NSURL*  theDoc = [[panel URLs] objectAtIndex:0];

        [self->_imageView setImage: [NSImage imageNamed: theDoc]];
    }

}];
```

}

Thanks!

Comment: `+[NSImage imageNamed:]` is not what you want. That gets a "named" image from the bundle, image catalog, or the working image cache. You probably want `-[NSImage initWithContentsOfFile:]' or a related method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the image is in application itself, then you can directly give the name of the image with extension in this method

```
[NSImage imageNamed:@"Image1.png"];
```

, but if you are giving the path, you should use this method:

```
[[NSImage alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:theDoc];
```

You can also check for the existence of the file at this path, just to be double sure you are going right.

I hope this helps you

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
- (IBAction)openExistingDocument:(id)sender {
NSOpenPanel* panel = [NSOpenPanel openPanel];

[panel beginWithCompletionHandler:^(NSInteger result){
    if (result == NSModalResponseOK) {
        NSURL*  theDoc = [[panel URLs] objectAtIndex:0];

        [self->_imageView setImage: [[NSImage alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:theDoc]];
    }

}];
```

You can use `[NSImage imageNamed:` when the image is in your Image Asset or in Bundle, While referring the image from Bundle give the complete image name with extension and if image is in Image Asset folder just the name will work. You should not provide URL to `[NSImage imageNamed:`

Comment: Hmmm.... still not working. I checked my outlets and all that. Just to be clear I am trying to grab an image from the users HDD